# Stuck at 800 x 600

Tags: login, 16.04, display-resolution

Today there was updates for my Ubuntu 16.04 (x64).

The updates were installed and it asked me to reboot.

After reboot I was unable to log into the graphic environment. It just looped to the login screen (Not the first time I have this problem)

After doing these steps:

```
service lightdm stop
sudo su -
cd /usr/local/bin
wget -Nc smxi.org/sgfxi
chmod +x sgfxi
sgfxi
```

I was able to login into graphic but I am stuck at `800 x 600`.
I was in `1080p` before the update.

Please help.

Comment: laptop,desktop? hardware? drivers? Could you give us some more info.

Comment: HP Envy 23 (All-in-one). In "Additional Drivers" I can choose between Nvidia and  X.Org X server. When I choose Nvidia it prevents me from login into gui (since I upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04) Either way I only can have a res of 800 x 600.

Comment: I also see in  "Additional Drivers" that the Nvidia is identified as GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] (GeForce GT 730A). It is hard to look around because all windows are bigger than the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Just had a little similar issue. For some reason it was not blacklisting the nouveau drivers. Remember to install the nvidia drivers before doing this.

Try this:

```
cd /etc/modprobe.d
ls
```

Now look if there is an nvidia or nouveau file there, if not:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

paste this at the bottom of the file:

```
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist nouveau
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
```

Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to save.

Now run:

```
update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

See if that works.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I really appreciate it . Gives me hope.

Comment: Unfortunately this changed nothing. I see that I have Nvidia 361.42 drivers installed. I did what you suggested and it seemed to do stuff and it did not fail. But with no different result. I am still unable to change my res from 800x600 and If I select the NVidia drivers I can't sign in to the GUI.

Comment: I really have no idea then :/ So sorry... Not really as good reponse, but did you upgrade from 15.10? If so, I would do a reinstall, but thats totally up to you. Maybe other people can help.

Answer (score 0):

I want to apologies in advance but this might not be accepted as an answer.

I was not able to fix that problem.
I want to add that I got a similar issue when I upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10.

In both case I was unable to boot all the way to the GUI and ended up burning a DVD and re-installing from scratch.

When I install from scratch the resolution is correct and I can boot into the GUI using the Nvidia driver.